# Module Federation for React host and NextJS remote app example/comfiguration

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I didn't find an example for a `react` host with and `nextjs` remote app
My host is working with a `react` remote app, now that I'm trying to add a `nextjs` remote app, it's not working:

- Ports:

  - Host `3000`
  - React remote `3001`
  - NextJS Remote `3002`
- In my host react app I have the following, in the `webpack.config.js` file

```
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'react_container',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        remote_react: 'remote_react@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js', // <- This is working
        remote_nextjs: 'remote_nextjs@http://localhost:3002/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js', // <- Not working :-(
      },
      exposes: {
        './react': 'react',
        './react-dom': 'react-dom',
      },
      shared: {
      },
    }),
```

And in the remote `nextjs` app in the `next.config.js` file

```
const { withFederatedSidecar } = require("@module-federation/nextjs-mf");

module.exports = withFederatedSidecar({
  name: "remote_nextjs",
  filename: "static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",
  exposes: {
    "./ExposedComponent": "./components/ExposedComponent",
  },
  shared: {
  },
})({
  // your original next.config.js export
});
```

- And finally, in the `App.jsx` of the host , I'm trying to consume the remote components like

```
import RemoteNav from 'remote_react/Nav'; // <- Working 
import ExposedComponent from 'remote_nextjs/ExposedComponent'; // <- Not working
```

- I have repo [here](https://github.com/OmerHerera/mfe-react-nextjs)

The error I'm getting its 404 from
http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/components_ExposedComponent_js.js

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the webpack config of the host, I can see that the next JS app is running on port 3002.

You are getting 404 error for next JS remote bundles when the host is trying to fetch the bundles from next JS server, it is hitting port 3000 instead of 3002. This is because the `next.config.js` does not have the updated `publicPath`.

Add the following in the place where it says `//your original next.config.js export` in the `next.config.js` file

```
webpack: (config) => {
  config.output.publicPath = "http://localhost:3002/_next/";
  return config;
}
```

This will set the `publicPath` of your next JS app to `port 3002` and fetch the bundles correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/ ,
on your remote app's webpack config, set publicPath would fix the path issue.

```
  export default {
    output: {
      publicPath: 'auto',
    },
    plugins: [...],
    ...
  }
```